# Remove "#DIV/0!" for average and standard deviation calculation

Tags: vba, excel

I calculate the average value and the standard deviation for values in a range of lines in the same column, but when there is no value entered in the columns for example, I get "#DIV/0!" in the cell where the average or stdev is supposed to appear, so how can I solve this problem so that I get the message "non calculated" for example instead of "#DIV/0!".

Here is how I enter the average formula in a cell :

```
newWorkBook.Worksheets("Feuil1").Range(Cells(29, i + 2).Address()).Formula = "=AVERAGE(" + Cells(19, i + 2).Address() + ":" + Cells(28, i + 2).Address() + ")"
```

**EDIT :** I have tried this :

```
newWorkBook.Worksheets("Feuil1").Range(Cells(29, i + 2).Address()).Formula = "=IFERROR(AVERAGE(" + Cells(19, i + 2).Address() + ":" + Cells(28, i + 2).Address() + ")" + "," + "non calculated" + ")"
```

And I get "#NOM?" instead of "non calculated" (PS : I'm using a french version of Excel, so in english it might be "#NAME?")

Comment: newWorkBook.Worksheets("Feuil1").Range(Cells(29, i + 2).Address()).Formula = "=IFERROR(AVERAGE(" & Cells(19, i + 2).Address() & ":" & Cells(28, i & 2).Address() & ")" & "," & "non calculated" & ")" use "&"'s not "+"'s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include `=IFERROR(AVERAGE(...), """" & "non calculated" & """")` around your current formula.

To inject a quotation literal into your source code, you need to write `""""`.

Comment: Sorry. Replace "non calculated" with """" & "non calculated" & """". You need a string literal in the formula,

Comment: It works now, thanks, please edit you answer with this additionnal information so that it appears clearly to the future readers of this post